# Use files from ALM as input for upload test

Tags: hp-uft, hp-alm

I try to store test files (pdf, docx, jpg) in `ALM` and use those as input files for upload tests. I am not sure, how could I copy files to `ALM` and after that how are these accessible from `UFT`.

Comment: Lot of examples already out there. Look at https://github.com/mvlaxminarayan/Learn/blob/5c19b26c2361494b5cb961c36b274cfc937bb137/WMOS_FRAMEWORK/Function_libs/ALM_Component_Library.qfl

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are lot of examples available online

```
Function get_ALM_Resources(gstr_FrameWorkPath,gstr_Resourcename,gstr_Foldername)
    'Dowload files from ALM TestResource

    Set objqcConn = QCUtil.QCConnection
    Set lobj_Resource = objqcConn.QCResourceFactory
    Set lobj_Filter = lobj_Resource.Filter

    lobj_Filter.Filter("RSC_FOLDER_NAME") = gstr_Foldername
    lobj_Filter.Filter("RSC_FILE_NAME") = gstr_Resourcename
    Set lobj_ResourceList = lobj_Filter.NewList
    If lobj_ResourceList.Count <>0 Then
        Set lobj_oFile = lobj_ResourceList.Item(1)
        lobj_oFile.FileName = gstr_Resourcename
        lobj_oFile.DownloadResource gstr_FrameWorkPath, True
    End If  
End Function
```

PS: Credits https://github.com/mvlaxminarayan/Learn/blob/5c19b26c2361494b5cb961c36b274cfc937bb137/WMOS_FRAMEWORK/Function_libs/ALM_Component_Library.qfl

```
Public Function fn_QCDownloadResource(sFileName, sDestination)  
    Dim objQC, objRes, objFilter, objFileList, objFile, sFilterPair, iCount
    If Not QCUtil.IsConnected Then  
        Exit Function
    End If  
    Set objQC = QCUtil.QCConnection
    Set objRes = objQC.QCResourceFactory
    Set objFilter =  objRes.Filter
    objFilter.Filter("RSC_NAME") = """" & Cstr(sFileName) & """"
    Set objFileList = objFilter.NewList

    If sDestination = "" Then
        sDestination = sDestination
    End if      
    If objFileList.Count = 1 Then
        Set objFile = objFileList.Item(1)
        objFile.FileName = sFileName & ".xlsx"
        objFile.DownloadResource sDestination, True   
    End If
    Set objQC = Nothing
    Set objRes = Nothing
    Set objFilter = Nothing
    Set objFileList = Nothing
    Set objFile = Nothing
End Function
```

PS: Credits https://github.com/PlusAutomationIkea/PlusAutomationSuite/blob/7489d362f0fcfef657da5f3284c830f84484eb51/FunctionLib/ALMHelper.qfl

```
Function DownloadQCAttachment(strQCDir, strFileName, strTargetPath)

    Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

    Set objFolder = QCUtil.QCConnection.TreeManager.NodeByPath(strQCDir) 
    Set objAttachmentList = objFolder.Attachments.NewList("") 

    For Each objAttachment In objAttachmentList 
        If InStr(1, objAttachment.DirectLink, strFileName, 1) > 0 Then
            Set objExtStorage = objAttachment.AttachmentStorage 
            objAttachmentName = objAttachment.DirectLink
            objExtStorage.Load objAttachmentName, true
            objFSO.MoveFile objExtStorage.ClientPath & "\" & objAttachmentName, strTargetPath & "\" & Split(objAttachment.Name, "_")(UBound(Split(objAttachment.Name, "_")))
            Exit For
        ElseIf strFileName = "" Then
            Set objExtStorage = objAttachment.AttachmentStorage 
            objAttachmentName = objAttachment.DirectLink
            objExtStorage.Load objAttachmentName, true
            objFSO.MoveFile objExtStorage.ClientPath & "\" & objAttachmentName, strTargetPath & "\" & Split(objAttachment.Name, "_")(UBound(Split(objAttachment.Name, "_")))
        End If
    Next

    Set objFSO = Nothing
End Function
```

PS: Credits https://github.com/Pradeep-ML/MobileLabsAutomationFramework/blob/248cd135848b5e159c770ab19ec73b7e981a9aad/FunctionLibraries/LoadTesting.qfl

Comment: Could you show me please, where and how can I upload the files? Where is file referenced in these code snippets?

Comment: Where you want to upload the file? resources, current run? current test?

Comment: To resources. These should be available for more test suites.

Comment: Look at the `UploadResource` method in https://github.com/Orasi/VBS-HP_UFT-Toolkit/blob/7ad4a3ec1cde5b08f877d0f63a650a9acfe800db/ALM

Comment: I see, so isn't any other interface for this purpose.

Comment: @plaidshirt, if the answer has helped, don't forget to accept it